# Process kill() returned unexpected error 1 Admob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have seen others recieve the error, but in my case I know which specific pod that is causing the error. Admob, using GoogleMobileAdsSDK, is throwing a process kill error. It might be related to my view controller or how I have installed the pods. I also just updated them and no change.
Here is my code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var banner: GADBannerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playSound()
        banner.adUnitID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
        banner.rootViewController = self
        banner.adSize = kGADAdSizeLargeBanner
        banner.load(GADRequest())
        // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
        // including entities and graphs.
       if let view = self.view as! SKView? { // setting the view to an SKScene
            let scene = MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size) // setting MenuScene as the first scene to display upon setup
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
        }
    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("Ad recieved")
    }
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print ("Not recieved")
        print (error)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.54.0~7.56.0, always got "Process kill() returned unexpected error 1 Admob". Now, only 7.53.1 can prevent this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I have been getting the error after upgrading Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK from 7.41.0 to 7.56 with cocoapods (and Firebase/Core from 4.13 to 6.18.0).